# Problems to fit with gnuplot and non-linear function

Tags: linux, gnuplot, curve-fitting

I have this set of data that want to fit with gnuplot using the function `f(x) = exp(A+ B/(x-x0))` where `A`,`B` and `x0` are my set of parameters to fit

```
# x   f(x)
0.382 8.29023731095968 
0.509 6.36124122026352 
0.637 4.66938977764103 
0.764 3.3194714217965
0.891 2.15140777817893
1.019 1.15428884806615 
1.146 0.262232461832655
```

I have try it with

```
fit log(f(x)) 'data.dat' using 1:(log($2)) via A, B, x0
```

also have defined the function as `f(x) = A+ B/(x-x0)` and tried with

```
fit f(x) 'data.dat' using 1:(log($2)) via A, B, x0
```

and then `plot exp(f(x))`

The code works but the fitted parameters are not fine, because when I plot the curve and the points together not make sense. Is this fit too complicate for gnuplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fitting can fail if you have an inappropriate function or if you have starting values which might make it difficult for the fitting procedure to converge.
In your case, I guess `x0` is an important parameter. You should help the gnuplot fitting algorithm a little to have a chance to find reasonable values. Here, I guess `x0=1.5` is a reasonable starting value. If this is not sufficient and if your model permits you might want to add additional variables or terms to get a better fit.

**Code:**

```
### fitting with appropriate starting values
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.382 8.29023731095968
0.509 6.36124122026352
0.637 4.66938977764103
0.764 3.3194714217965
0.891 2.15140777817893
1.019 1.15428884806615
1.146 0.262232461832655
EOD

A = 1
B = 1
x0 = 1.5
f(x) = exp(A + B/(x-x0))
set fit nolog

fit f(x) $Data u 1:2 via A,B,x0

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 ti "Data",\
     f(x) w l lc rgb "red" ti "Fit"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
A               = 4.61445          +/- 0.3907       (8.466%)
B               = 3.57094          +/- 0.8876       (24.86%)
x0              = 1.80616          +/- 0.1371       (7.593%)
```

[image]